# represent counting variable in 4 digit hex seperated by a space

Tags: python, format, hex

I'd need a method to represent an int `i` in hex in 4 digits, seperated by a space after the second digit. e.g.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print insert_magic(i)
```

which then should look like this:

```
00 01
00 02
00 03
...
```

I've accomplished the 4 digit representation but without a space, with:

```
print format(i,'04x')
```

Comment: I can't find this in the format minilanguage docs, maybe you could just split the string after formatting?

Comment: I considered doing so already and will do that if there's no *direct* way of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way

```
for i in range(15):
    print '{}{} {}{}'.format(*format(i, '04x')) #
```

this unpacks the hex string and we can achieve it

how it works.

1. `format(i, '04x')` --> gives a 4 digit hexadecimal string
2. think if `str='abcd'`  `*str=['a','b','c','d']` simillarly `0001` becomes `['0','0','0','1']`
3. now we unpack the list and place each value for `{}`

Comment: thats it! thank you very much! would you mind explaining how this works?